# ASF duration is 29 secs, WMP plays 25 secs. How come?

Tags: video, wmp, asf, dmo

I've created a custom ASF file containing compressed voice + screen streams.

The total duration of the file according to the header is 29 secs.

When opening it in WMP (using custom DMOs to play the streams), the file plays 25 seconds, and then the seek bar snaps to the beginning, but oddly, WMP continues to play 4 more seconds before stopping.

Looking at the ASF with ASF Viewer - there are 29 seconds of packets , and both "play duration" and "send duration" are 29 seconds. Why would WMP only see 25 seconds??

Thanks

Comment: BTW - Preroll is 3 seconds and since it is impossible to have a preroll of less than 3 seconds, I don't see why it should cause this...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the WMP progress bar is being updated before the packets are played, instead of after.

Comment: And why is that? What can I do about it?

Comment: Check your advanced systems format file to make sure the format is correct.  If you are sure the format is correct, report the problem with Windows Media Player to Microsoft.

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft approved MPEG-4 compression?

Comment: I'm not using any known compression, the data inside the ASF is a proprietary format which the DMO decodes.

The format is obviously correct since WMP plays it very well, only the timing is wrong for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior when the ASF index was corrupted, i.e. when the index entry at 25 seconds points to the first data packet in your case.